# Stateless Widget for Checkbox and TextField

Tags: flutter, statefulwidget, statelesswidget

When i use Checkbox in StatelessWidget, I can't change checkbox to checked/unchecked at runtime
but it's work if i use StatefulWidget.

But, why i can change (typing) TextField value  when I use StatelessWidget?

Comment: Widget redraws when you click checkbox, thats why you need stateful widget,
But In Stateless widget, the function returns the value but it doesn't redraw the widget

Answer (score 0):

it's because you set/update checkbox value in your custom widget and if it's stateless you cant see changes because you can't use `setState` and redraw widget tree

but TextField update value inside itself widget and TextField is a stateful widget

```
class TextField extends StatefulWidget
```